# How do I exclude additional properties using express-validator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I am using `express-validator` in my express app, and I am attempting to prevent additional fields being specified on POST requests. This is because I am passing the value of `req.body` to my ORM to insert into the database, and I want to avoid having to explicitly map between my inserted object and request body alongside adding validators.

Is this possible? I can't seem to find it in the documentation. Using JSON Schema you can do this with `additionalProperties: false`

Answer (score 10):

After some more research, I found that it's possible to do with with the [Matched Data API](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/matched-data-api.html)

In my express controller I can now do;

```js
const { matchedData } = require('express-validator');
(req, res) => {
  const matched = matchedData(req, {
    includeOptionals: true,
  });
  db.insert(matched)
  ...
}
```